# как сделать разрыв в окружности и поместить туда элемент?

Tags: html, css

[image]

У меня не получается выполнение данного блока, как можно сделать разрыв в окружности?

Comment: поищите примеры по запросу `css arc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делается при помощи тега [fieldset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset), нашёл по нему информацию и сверстал решение за 5 минут, советую сначала гуглить.

Само решение:

```css
.border {
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
.border__title {
  text-align: center;
}
.border__title img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.content {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="border">
  <legend class="border__title">
    <img src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/303113.svg" alt="">  
  </legend>
  <div class="content">
      Какой-то контент
  </div>  
</fieldset>
```

Тег `<fieldset>` создаёт границу. 
Тег `<legend>` создаёт заголовок границы.